# Why the closed loop integral is zero

Tags: integration

I have a integral :

$\oint_L \frac{1}{r^2} dr $

Which I can write as :

$-\oint_L  d(1/r) $
r is here the  distance on that plane from a point.
Why is this equal to zero?

Is it because the beginning and end points are same and therefore the close loop integral will give zero?

Comment: Is this a complex integral around a closed loop in the complex plane?

Comment: I picked a random plane which is not complex.

Comment: What is $r$ here? Is it the distance of a point in a plane?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Answer (score 1):

Interpreting your place as $\Bbb C$, on a radius-$a$ loop centred on the origin $z=a\exp i\theta$, so $$\oint_L\frac{dr}{r^2}=\frac{i}{a}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-i\theta}d\theta=0.$$